# Prepared Statement errors

Tags: netbeans

I am having errors.
When I run the file, it is stated that
"  INFO:   SQL Exception hit: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0).   "

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
          "UPDATE Customers SET Contact = " + contact_num + "," 
          + "Email = '" + email_add + "'," 
          + "Address = '" + mail_add + "'," 
          + "SurveyStatus = " + radio_group + ","
          + "Subscription = " + receive_info + " " 
  + "WHERE MembershipID = '" + member_ID + "' " );

          pst.setString(2,contact_num);
          pst.setString(3,email_add);
          pst.setString(4,mail_add);
          pst.setString(5,radio_group);
          pst.setString(6,receive_info);
          pst.setString(1,member_ID);

           stmt.executeUpdate(strSqlnsert);
            pst.executeUpdate(strSqlUpdate);
```

I've got another error for this,stated that  Syntax Error

```
"INSERT INTO Customers(MembershipID,Contact,Email,Address,SurveyStatus,Subscription) VALUES"
  + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?" + "," + "?");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `PreparedStatement`, use the `?` character without any quotes to indicate a parameter replacement.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
      "UPDATE Customers SET Contact = ?," 
      + "Email = ?," 
      + "Address = ?," 
      + "SurveyStatus = ?,"
      + "Subscription = ? " 
      + "WHERE MembershipID = ? " );
```

You're defeating the purpose of a `PreparedStatement` by substituting values directly. Then your `pst.setString()` calls are meaningless since there aren't any `?`'s to replace.

The error message is appearing because the parser is counting `?`'s, and finds zero. When you do `.setString()` the first time it's panicking.

Also note that you'll need to change the indexes in your `.setString()` calls. `member_ID` is the last `?`, so it should be number 6 and the other indexes should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Don't use a question-mark in place of a variable, just put them in the string, like this:  `myStatementSql = "INSERT INTO Customers (MembershipID, Contact, Email, Address, SurveyStatus, Subscription) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`

Comment: INFO:   SQL Exception hit: Data truncated for column 'Subscription' at row 1

Comment: Sounds like the datatype you're using on the Java side doesn't match that on the SQL. Is the Subscription value in Java longer than the database can handle, maybe?

Comment: weird. for my UPDATE , it still can work. BUt for insert, it don't

Comment: Make sure the datatypes in your `.setXXX()` methods match those of the database as well. There's no real way to enforce type-safety across the Java/database boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Write your prepared statement like this:

```
PreparedStatement pst =      conn.prepareStatement( "UPDATE Customers SET   Contact =?,  Email = ?, Address = ?,SurveyStatus =?,Subscription =? WHERE MembershipID =?" );
```